# np.busday_count between two date columns gives -1 as a result for every row

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating working days between two date columns. I have converted these columns to datetime using pandas. when i use numpy to calculate the no of working days i get -1 for every row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Date check
yesterday = date.today()-timedelta(1)
open_date = yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
prior_yesterday = date.today()- timedelta(2)
opendate=prior_yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
currentdate = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

open = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Desktop\Open.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'Open',
                     header = 0,
                     )
```

This is being calculated based on previous day as the items are open when the data is extracted.

```
for index , row in open.iterrows():
    open['Open_Date'] = open_date

open['CREATE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(open['CREATE'])
open['OPEN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(open['Open_Date'])

for index , row in open.iterrows():
    open['Open_Days'] =np.busday_count(row['CREATE_DATE'],row['OPEN_DATE'])
```

Old Format of date is in string so i changed the entire column to date and time format

```
CREATE      Open_Date   CREATE_DATE          OPEN_DATE
09/05/2018  10/23/2018  2018-09-05 00:00:00 2018-10-23 00:00:00
10/02/2018  10/23/2018  2018-10-02 00:00:00 2018-10-23 00:00:00
10/17/2018  10/23/2018  2018-10-17 00:00:00 2018-10-23 00:00:00
10/17/2018  10/23/2018  2018-10-17 00:00:00 2018-10-23 00:00:00
```

This is the date format that i have.

How do i avoid this.

Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand why this is not working. An indication to why this is not working is that in the for loop on the left-hand-side (the assignment) the row or index is not present anywhere.

Each step in the loop creates a single value and fills it in the DataFrame over and over:

```
# Iterate over each row of the DataFrame
for index , row in open.iterrows():
    # count business days for current row
    bday_count = np.busday_count(row['CREATE_DATE'],row['OPEN_DATE'])
    # create a new column in the DataFrame
    # broadcast `bday_count` to every value
    open['Open_Days'] = bday_count
```

So in the end the `Open_Days` column contains the `bday_count` from the last row. All the earlier values have been overwritten at each iteration.

The earlier for loop that fills `Open_Date` can be skipped completely, just set `open['Open_Date'] = open_date` once. This could also be indicated that its a loop but the body uses neither `index`, nor `row`!

If you want to apply a function along the rows in pandas, use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
df["Open_Days"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x.CREATE_DATE, x.OPEN_DATE), axis=1)
```

Comment: `if open['REASSIGNDATE'].any()=='':
    open['OPEN_DAYS']=open.apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x.CREATEDATE,x.OPEN_DATE),axis =1) 
else:
    open['OPEN_DAYS']=open.apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x.REASSIGNDATE,x.OPEN_DATE),axis =1)` i get ValueError: ('cannot convert float NaN to integer', 'occurred at index 0'). Few rows in REASSIGNDATE are blank.

Comment: using np.where i get cannot use key word error when i assigned these two to different variables and checked them. using something like this np.where('REASSIGNDATE' ='' , S1,S2)

Comment: Have a look at Pandas dropna and fillna functions. If that doesn’t help, create a new question with some example data. It’s too had to read code in these comments.

Comment: i created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010214/network-days-calculation-between-3-days-one-column-would-have-blank-values